# Get Dates that match a periodicity and get number of sequence

Tags: java, date, periodicity

I need to know if a date match a periodicity, for example, periodicity is 1 hour, and date that user gives is 13/09/2021 23:00, the inicial that my java code should take is 13/09/2021 00:00 and check how many times have to add 1 hour to get the date 13/09/2021 23:00.

The idea now is made a loop and add 1hour to the date and save in an array, then check if the date is inside the array and the position. Is there any other way?

Comment: So you want to know how many hours are there from midnight to that particular time?

Comment: Is the end goal to calculate how many hours lie between the two dates?

Comment: Qbrute the example is for 1 hour, but I would like to use with 5 minutes, 15 minutes...

Comment: @AbishekStephen in this example is 1 hour but I would use with 5, 15 minutes...

Comment: Please update your question to include all the requirements of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to calculate how many hours there are between two dates. For that, it's cleaner to use the built-in `java.time` classes. You can read the two dates into `LocalDateTime` objects and calculate the time span between them with `ChronoUnit.HOURS`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.parse("13/09/2021 00:00", formatter);
LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.parse("13/09/2021 23:00", formatter);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(start, end);
```

The result will be `23`.

For various other units (minutes for example), there's `ChronoUnit.MINUTES`. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html). There are a lot of different units to choose from.

Comment: I think It can help me , going to see if ChronoUnit.Minutes is also available then i divide by 5,10 or 15 and I have the times from the original date. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am adding a couple of minor refinements compared to the correct answer by QBrute.

1. The periodicity can be any amount of time in hours, minutes and seconds.
2. I am taking time zone into account so we also get correct results across summer time transitions (spring forward and fall back) and other time anomalies.
3. If there isn’t a whole number of periodicities, I am rounding up to be sure to have at least enough.

   ```
   ZoneId userTimeZone = ZoneId.of("Africa/Dar_es_Salaam");

   Duration periodicity = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
   ZonedDateTime userTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 9, 13, 23, 0, 0, 0, userTimeZone);
   ZonedDateTime initialTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2021, 9, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, userTimeZone);

   Duration timeBetween = Duration.between(initialTime, userTime);
   long numberOfPeriodicities = timeBetween.dividedBy(periodicity);
   // Has truncation occurred?
   if (initialTime.plus(periodicity.multipliedBy(numberOfPeriodicities)).isBefore(userTime)) {
       // Need one more periodicity
       numberOfPeriodicities++;
   }

   System.out.println(numberOfPeriodicities);
   ```

Output is:

> 276

If you want a periodicity of 7.5 minutes, specify `Duration.ofMinutes(7).plusSeconds(30)`. The `Duration.dividedBy(Duration)` method that I am using was introduced in Java 9.

Link: [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.